# Does a change in pecking order imply illness?

Tags: guinea-pigs, dominance

I have had four guinea pigs for a little over a year now.

When I got them, they soon established a clear order amongst themselves.  When I feed them they have always gone to the food and/or my hand in the same sequence.

In the last couple of weeks, this has changed.  The leader has been toppled.

While there is no sign of any illness, lethargy, aggression or loss of appetite, it concerns me that there is this change.

Is it common for the pecking order to change or is there some indication here of illness in the former leader?